# Swift array of different types

Tags: arrays, swift

As I know array is value type in Swift, there are no references.

Could you please explain me the following situation:

```
var arr: [Any] = [1, "1", UIView(), "qwerty"]
print(arr[3] as! String)
```

How is "arr[3]" O(1) operation. How is it possible to get the third element without iteration?

Comment: Are you asking specifically why the array can be simply indexed using arithmetic, when the types of the elements are ostensibly different? If so, then I guess they're implemented as pointers to the actual concrete types. That said, I guess it could alternatively work by adding the appropriate offset at compile time, given known types, but that would only work in cases where the types could be known then, and it's pretty clear such an array would really be implemented using pointers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> As I know array is value type in Swift, there are no references.

The second half is incorrect. A type `T` being a value type just means that this code prints "1, 2", instead of "2, 2":

```
var a = T()
a.someIntProperty = 1
var b = a
b.someIntProperty = 2
print("\(a.someIntProperty), \(b.someIntProperty)")
```

Being a value/reference type implies a set of behaviours, not how the type is implemented under the hood.

As you said, for the array accesses to work at O(1) time, the array will need to contain pointers to the elements of the array, which are all of the same size. This does not make `Array` a "non-value type", because the whole array is still copied when you reassign variables of type `[Any]`. Another, possibly more convincing reason, is that the entire value of the array is still stored in `arr`. It's just that it's a bunch of pointers to the elements. If `Array` truly were a reference type, `arr` would store one pointer, pointing to the value of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are stored sequentailly in blocks inside memory so with index it's a calculation that's of **O(2)** that refers to a pointer to the actual data content most likely only with `Any` where size of each element differs